# Validate a textbox to accept numbers thats between 0 to 100 only

Tags: javascript

I have a  textbox labeled "score". I want the user to enter a value between 0 and 100. How can I validate the value provided by the user?

HTML:

```
<div class="editor-label"> Score </div> 
<div class="editor-field"> 
    <input type="text" name="Score" id="Score" maxlength="25" /> 
    <span id="ScoreError" class="error"></span>
</div>
```

What I tried so far:

```
var num = document.getElementById("Score").value; 
if (num < 0 || num > 100){
    document.getElementById("ScoreError").innerHTML = "- Score is required.";
    alert("Enter a Score thats between 0 to 100") 
    isValidForm = false; 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an `<input>`, set _type_ to `number`, _min_ `0`, _max_ `100` and _value_ `0`? http://jsfiddle.net/A7EFa/

Comment: take a look [here](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range)

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting code in comments. The condition looks OK to me. When/how are you running the code?

Comment: running it through wamp server editing my codes using notepad++

Comment: its not validating when is (num < 0 || num > 100) but when i change it to (num < 1 || num > 100) its validating

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of any non-numeric characters using `var num = document.getElementById("Score").value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")` and then your if/then statement will be looking at an integer.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7FXxt/